# The moment that I can get the actual url after transition in Ember

Tags: ember.js

How can I get the real url? When is the moment when I can get the url with the view loaded? What is this moment in the code? Maybe in Ember code, to do something depending I get a url o another.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform an action when the URL changes, you can use the `didTransition` event in your route.

```
App.YourRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    didTransition: function() {
        // do stuff
    }
  }
});
```

If all you want to log all transitions for debug purposes, then you can simply set the configuration as follows. (See [Understanding Ember.Js: Debugging](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/debugging/))

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
  // Basic logging, e.g. "Transitioned into 'post'"
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true, 

  // Extremely detailed logging, highlighting every internal
  // step made while transitioning into a route, including
  // `beforeModel`, `model`, and `afterModel` hooks, and
  // information about redirects and aborted transitions
  LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true
});
```

Comment: Thank for reply. I want to do something depending of URL in each moment. Also I want to get a trace o navigation

Comment: didInsertElement is a controller event? Are you sure?

Comment: Ok, doing window.location.href in that action I get the next. When I start my app, the url is right, I logging my user, the url changes but window.location.href give me the same url that the principal view. Then I do another transition and the url given is the previous. If I return to the previous view, the url given is also the previous (right), but if I do another transition more, the url given is repeated, the previous same

Comment: I've checked that when the transition is completed (didTransition), the new url is not set yet

Comment: I'm still not 100% clear on what you are trying to do. The ember way of doing "something" when the URL changes is to base transition logic in the routes. What specific need do you have that cannot be implemented in that manner?

Comment: I need to know the URL at all times. centralized manner. I want to monitorize url changes